# Allegro 5 game: How do I set a resolution that is appropriate for the aspect ratio of the screen?

Tags: fullscreen, resolution, widescreen, allegro5

Using Allegro 5, how do initialize a game in fullscreen mode so that it respects the format of the screen (widescreen 16:9 vs normal 3:4)

```
al_create_display (w, h)
```

Let's you select any ratio you want. For example you can set 640x480, regardless of the screen size. But it will look weird on a widescreen monitor.
How do you know which ratio to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, I can answer this as well - use [`al_get_monitor_info`()](http://docs.liballeg.org/display.html#allegro_monitor_info).

```
al_get_monitor_info(0, &info);
w = info.x2 - info.x1; /* Assume this is 1366 */
h = info.y2 - info.y1; /* Assume this is 768 */
al_create_display(w, h);
```

Now you can either render everything in a 640x480 rectangle centered within 1366x768 to make it appear pixel-perfect, or alternatively scale your graphics up by 768/480 and keep two black bars to the left and right. If you use OpenGL for rendering, both are very easy to do by simply altering the projection matrix.